# DNS: How to resolve "Duplicate A and CNAME records are not supported"

Tags: domain-name-system

I am hosting a site (zippee.net) on Amazon S3.  Also using CloudFront and Amazon Certificate Manager.  The DNS is at Namesecure, which the owner of the site had set up before I started working with him.

The site has been in existence almost a year now, so I was required to enter two new CNAME records in the Zone File at Namesecure in order for the ACM certificate to be renewed.  There was already a `*.zippee.net` A Record before I entered the new CNAME records.  After entering the two new CNAME records, I am getting an error message:

`Duplicate A and CNAME records are not supported due to domain name resolution issues. The hostname _5B0931AD329DFD43F578E5FF20EEDEEC.ZIPPEE.NET. can not be used twice.`

Should I delete the `*.zippee.net` A record?

I could also recommend to the owner that we transfer the DNS to AWS Route 53, if that's the easiest or best solution.

Here is the full zone file:

```
MX Records:
A Records:
  *.zippee.net. IN A 205.178.189.131
  zippee.net. IN A 205.178.189.131
CNAME Records:
  www.zippee.net. IN CNAME d143bf7yw34gox.cloudfront.net.
  _5b0931ad329dfd43f578e5ff20eedeec.zippee.net. IN CNAME _299e4f74454dd9ead90a9a33d471e9cd.olprtlswtu.acm-validations.aws.
  _7ac1f8dbb2095ebd09cc1e30690d7952.www..zippee.net. IN CNAME _b00720baaee114f1090bae251c05f1b4.olprtlswtu.acm-validations.aws.
TXT Records:
```

Comment: check for double entries as the text says

Comment: Can you show the actual records that you have? A wildcard would not expand to specific names that are added, so that *should* not interfere, but maybe there is something else going on.

Comment: You can not have two CNAME records on the same name, nor a CNAME record and any other record type on the same name.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Thank you! I have added the actual records in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was two dots in `www..zippee.net`

It probably saw this as simply `zippee.net`, which was a duplicate.

Moral of the story:  *If I stare at something long enough, there's always a chance I will eventually see it.*